# Grails one line (abbreviated) attribute constraint definition possible?

Tags: grails

If I have a class with many properties that share identical attribute constraints like this:

```
class myClass {

    String thisString
    String thatString
    String theOtherString

    static constraints = {
        thisString(nullable: true)
        thatString(nullable: true)
        theOtherString(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

Is there an easier "one line" way to declare the static constraints? Something akin to say:

```
static constraints = {
    thisString, thatString, theOtherString(nullable:true)
}
```

? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails has something known as [Global Constraints](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html). This allows you to reuse identical constraints between many different GORM objects.

grails-app/conf/Config.groovy

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    mySharedConstraint(nullable:true, ...)
}
```

myClass.groovy

```
class myClass {

    String thisString
    String thatString
    String theOtherString

    static constraints = {
        thisString(shared: mySharedConstraint)
        thatString(shared: mySharedConstraint)
        theOtherString(shared: mySharedConstraint)
    }
}
```

If you don't even want to to that...you can simply apply constraints to everything by doing something like this:

```
grails.gorm.default.constaints = {
    '*'(nullable:true)
}
```

The start will apply this to all properties.

In the end, I would consult the link above. Good Luck!